# Bitcoin transactions.

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, wallet

So recently, I had some bitcoins transferred to my desktop wallet account. The transfer happened yesterday. The way I did it, was that I created an address as you all know, without label or specific amount of bitcoins receiving. Then, that address, I pasted it on the website I am using to mine bitcoins, so when the Bitcoins were ready to be transferred, they already could use the address I provided. I still don't see them reflected on my desktop wallet and I am little concerned whether they will show up or not.

Thank you guys, if anything please let me know if this scenario happens often or not, so I take it easy.

Comment: Are you sure the website/company you are working with sent you the funds? Did they provide you with a transaction hash? You should be able to check a blockexplorer to see if the transaction was broadcast to the network. If not it sounds like the issue is with that mining service.

Comment: Yes, the one I am using is Genesis-Mining. They also did provide me a transaction hash. I checked it but I don't understand how to view the chart. Anyways, also the wallet I am also using is Bitcoin core. I think I am good, but maybe something might not be right about not showing up on time (talking about the transaction being reflected in my bitcoin core account).

Comment: It could be that your bitcoin core node is still syncing with the network so it's not showing the transaction yet. What's the transaction hash?